# class not found but i sure the jar is exist?

Tags: java, tomcat

my project is a plateforme web services
the web services will connect with a external system 
the method's web service will invok a command of the external system

i generated my the .war file and i depploy my project with tomcat7 and for no any problem
but when i tried to execute the method in web service this error appeared

```
Error code: FUNC_UTIL.SAXParserError
ClassName: com.lhs.ccb.func.ect.SystemException
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\serveur\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\Registry.xml (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
Error arguments: 
IO
C:\serveur\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\Registry.xml (Le fichier spécifié est introuvable)
     Stack trace:
 [com.lhs.ccb.func.reg.RegistryParser.parseToNode(Unknown Source), com.lhs.ccb.func.reg.Registry.load(Unknown   Source), com.lhs.ccb.func.reg.Registry.getInstance(Unknown Source),    com.lhs.ccb.cfw.cda.session.ApplicationSettings.getAttribute(Unknown Source),    com.lhs.ccb.cfw.cda.servicelayer.connectionpool.ConnectionPoolManager.getConnection(Unknown Source),   com.lhs.ccb.cfw.cda.servicelayer.connectionpool.ConnectionPoolManager.getConnection(Unknown Source),   com.services.ServiceCustomerRead.call_AREA_CODE(ServiceCustomerRead.java:36),     com.ws.CustomerRead.outputAREA_CODE(CustomerRead.java:27), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method), sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57), sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43), java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601), com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250), com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:150), com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:261), com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100), com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641), com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600), com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585), com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482), com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:314), com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:608), com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259), com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:207), com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159), com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194), com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647), javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305), org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123), org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171), org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99), org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953), org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118), org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408), org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023), org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589), org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145), java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615), java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)]
at com.lhs.ccb.func.reg.RegistryParser.parseToNode(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.func.reg.Registry.load(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.func.reg.Registry.getInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.cfw.cda.session.ApplicationSettings.getAttribute(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.cfw.cda.servicelayer.connectionpool.ConnectionPoolManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.lhs.ccb.cfw.cda.servicelayer.connectionpool.ConnectionPoolManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.services.ServiceCustomerRead.call_AREA_CODE(ServiceCustomerRead.java:36)
at com.ws.CustomerRead.outputAREA_CODE(CustomerRead.java:27)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.server.InstanceResolver$1.invoke(InstanceResolver.java:250)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.InvokerTube$2.invoke(InvokerTube.java:150)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointMethodHandler.invoke(EndpointMethodHandler.java:261)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.SEIInvokerTube.processRequest(SEIInvokerTube.java:100)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.__doRun(Fiber.java:641)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber._doRun(Fiber.java:600)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.doRun(Fiber.java:585)
at com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber.runSync(Fiber.java:482)
at com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2.process(WSEndpointImpl.java:314)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:608)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:259)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.invokeAsync(ServletAdapter.java:207)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:159)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:194)
at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet.doPost(WSSpringServlet.java:52)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\serveur\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\Registry.xml (Le fichier  spécifié est introuvable)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:609)
at    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:189)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:799)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
... 45 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't read the stack trace properly.  The problem is not a missing class.  Rather, it is a `java.io.FileNotFoundException` which means that Tomcat tried to open a file in the file system ... and couldn't find it.

The file that is missing is `C:\serveur\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\bin\Registry.xml`; i.e. in the server's `bin`  A file in the web server's `bin` directory won't be installed from a WAR file.

Comment: Either create/install the file by hand, or modify your application to open the file from the classpath so that you can load it from the webapp.

Comment: what means install the file by hand